# Difficulty blurring python image

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, blur, scikit-image

I'm having trouble with blurring an image. I am trying to use the Gaussian blur filter from skimage. The image I am working with was downloaded to the environment from a url. Below is the code I have.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import skimage
import skimage.transform
from skimage import io
from skimage import color
from skimage import data
from skimage import filters
from skimage import img_as_float


url = 'https://github.com/jagar2/Summer_2020_MAT-395-495_Scientific-Data-Analysis-and-Computing/blob/master/homeworks/HW2/Zebra.jpg?raw=true'

zebra = io.imread(url)

print(type(zebra))
print(zebra.dtype)
print(zebra.shape)
print(zebra.min(), zebra.max())

plt.imshow(zebra)

# make a copy of the original 
zebra_copy = np.copy(zebra)

# convert image to grayscale
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
     
zebra_gray = rgb2gray(zebra_copy)    
grayscale = plt.imshow(zebra_gray, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show(grayscale)
```

All of the above code runs as expected. Below is the code I am running to blur the image and I also get the error below.

```
blur = filters.gaussian(grayscale, sigma=1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7533f0f238e2> in <module>()
----> 1 blur = filters.gaussian(grayscale, sigma=1)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skimage/filters/_gaussian.py in _guess_spatial_dimensions(image)
    137         If the image array has less than two or more than four dimensions.
    138     """
--> 139     if image.ndim == 2:
    140         return 2
    141     if image.ndim == 3 and image.shape[-1] != 3:

AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Any tips on how to fix this to get the blurred image is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your imports. I do not know what io.imread is referring to.

Comment: just added them @SagarPatil

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.gaussian), `filters.gaussian` takes array-like (e.g. `numpy.ndarray`) as input.

However, in

```
blur = filters.gaussian(grayscale, sigma=1)
```

`grayscale` is `matplotlib.image.AxesImage`.

If you pass `numpy.ndarray`, it should work.

e.g.

```
blur = filters.gaussian(zebra_gray, sigma=1)
```

---

Try:

```
In[1]: type(zebra_gray)
Out[1]: numpy.ndarray

In[2]: type(grayscale)
Out[2]: matplotlib.image.AxesImage
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is probably due to the conversion to grayscale. Normally, all sRGB images have 3 color channels that have intensity values for each color of a pixel. The number of color channels is what ndim is referring to. When the image is converted to grayscale, the color channel dimension is removed as there is need for only 1 color channel. Try not converting the image to grayscale and see what happens.

If you really need the image to be in grayscale, then convert the grayscale image back to RGB(the color will not come back as the grayscale image does not contain that information).

Comment: I am ultimately trying to segment the zebra to be a different color. I read that converting to grayscale and then blurring may help with this. I will try just blurring the RGB image.

Comment: What do you mean by segment to be a different color?

Comment: My desired result is to be a zebra with different color strips, instead of black and white. I am trying to segment the image so that I can only change the color of the zebra while not altering the background. This is why I thought converting to grayscale and blurring would be efficient so I could then create a threshold to turn the pixels in the background  'off' so I can only alter the color of the zebra. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Oh I see. In this case, converting to grayscale might actually make your job more difficult. Just blurring the RGB image and using a RGB or HSV threshold to get masks can get the job done. Also, you can use GRIP(https://wpiroboticsprojects.github.io/GRIP/#/) to build computer vision pipelines. It uses OpenCV under the hood, and its extremely useful for building vision pipelines.